# how to get the errors and crashs details into a separate file?

Tags: iphone, xcode

We can get our crash details and errors in console but is there anyway **to get the errors and crash details into a separate file** i need to create a separate log file

Could any please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when ever your app crashes in your iPAD or iPhone. it saves the crash file.
and when you synch the device to your itunes it copies the crash file to your system.

you can get the crash report at this location

User/library/logs/crashReporter/MobileDevice/your_device_name.

and you can easily check your logs in log navigator in xcode.

and forget to copy the .dysm file of your app( right click on your app in xcode>>show in finder>>(there you will find the .dysm file)

Steps to analyze crash report from apple:

Copy the release .app file, the .dSYM file that was created at the time of release and the crash report  into a FOLDER.

OPEN terminal application and go to the folder created above (using CD command)

atos -arch armv7 -o ''/'<.dSYM filename here>' . The memory location should be the one at which  the app crashed as per the report.

Example for Foo.app: atos -arch armv7 -o 'Foo.app'/'Foo' 0x0003b508

This would show you the exact line, method name which resulted in crash.

Comment: is it possble for us save that

Comment: where exactly the crash occurs

Comment: all is saved to that folder in your crash report. you just have to follow the steps mentioned above

Comment: @Deepak if you find the above answer helpful then pls mark it as correct. thank you